# Does Google Tag Manager interpret a variable with string value 'false' as a boolean false?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I set up a new data layer variable in Tag Manager that will represent whether an event is a non-interaction hit. This is supposed to be a boolean true/false value. I set the default value of `false` (without quotes).

I noticed when I explicitly include this variable as a boolean in my events, eg:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'gaEvent', ..., 'nonInteractionHit': false});
```

Tag Manager's preview mode shows in the event properties `Non-Interaction Hit: false` as a **boolean** (without quotes). This is expected.

However, when I don't specify a value for nonInteractionHit, eg:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'gaEvent', ...});
```

The preview mode shows the event fired with `Non-Interaction Hit: 'false'` as as a **string** value (with quotes). Basically, it seems to have interpreted my default value as a string instead of a boolean. This is concerning, because JavaScript is awesome and the string `'false'` is actually *truthy*.

So my question is: Does GTM consider string representations of 'false' or 'true' as proper booleans, or just strings, specifically when used in the context of a property that is supposed to be a boolean? Does `'false'` actually evaluate to `false` as I need it, in my case?

Extra credit: is there a way to specify a variable's default value as a proper boolean? The UI doesn't seem to allow it - you just get a textbox to enter a value which apparently is interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I've found the general answer to my question, but I'll leave this open if anyone wants to provide a better answer.

I found my answer here: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/fun-google-tag-manager-part-2/#true-and-false

I'm not certain exactly how 'false' is interpreted in my situation setting Non-Interaction Hit, but it does seem certain GTM variables do require a boolean type, and entering `true` or `false` in a field (without quotes) is interpreted as a string, and may not work as expected. And unfortunately you can't specify boolean true/false in GTM text fields.

Simo's elegant workaround is to instead also define {{true}} and {{false}} variables based on a Javascript snippet, which is written as `function(){return true;}` and `function(){return false;}`, respectively. Then, in my case I can set the default value to the variable `{{false}}`. I've verified that in preview mode, this shows up as a proper, un-quoted boolean value.

Further proof: When I had the default value entered as the text `false` entered in the text box, and then set a formatting override for "Convert false to..." and specified some arbitrary new value. When I fired the event, it *was not* overridden. It showed the value as `'false'`. Hence, GTM's own override system didn't interpret the text `false` as a boolean. It also didn't interpret it as true, either...

Take away: use your own `{{true}}` and `{{false}}` variables to be sure you are assigning a proper boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same/similar issue just now when setting up a trigger that would only fire when a dataLayer variable was set to false i.e. it was being recorded as "boolean" false, not "string" "false". The method of adding custom script variables to return boolean true/false doesn't work when creating trigger (for example), because the value can only be a text input. I did however use the false variable to set the default value of my dataLayer variable so it wasn't returned as undefined.

I can confirm that putting a string "false" in the "value" works, so GTM must be doing a toString() on the boolean. Example below shows the dataLayer variable "Is Booking Engine" which is being set as true on the booking website but not defined otherwise
[image]

This image shows using the "Is Booking Engine" variable in the trigger, note that the value "false" is just typed in, not selected from an option or something.

[image]